FullSimplify gives wrong result for a symbolic expression (involving Abs, Conjugate, Sqrt, etc. )
I defined functions omegabar and sutosl for inputs gamma and omega, where
{omega \[Element] Reals && gamma \[Element] Complexes && Abs[gamma] < 1}

Problem: (In the following picture) The result of substitution of a specific value turns out to be different from the result of first applying FullSimplify to the symbolic expression and then applying substitution.

Here are the functions (in simple forms) needed:
omegabar[mat_] :=
 If[Abs[mat[[1, 1]] + mat[[2, 2]]] < 2,
  Sign[mat[[2, 1]] - mat[[1, 2]]]*
   ArcCos[(mat[[1, 1]] + mat[[2, 2]])/2],
  0]

sutosl[gammaomega_] := Module[{gamma, omega},
  gamma = gammaomega[[1]];
  omega = gammaomega[[2]];
  {{Re[E^(I omega) (1 + gamma)]/Sqrt[1 - Abs[gamma]^2], (
    Im[E^(I omega)] + Im[E^(I omega) gamma])/Sqrt[
    1 - Abs[gamma]^2]}, 
  {(-Im[E^(I omega)] + Im[E^(I omega) gamma])/
    Sqrt[1 - Abs[gamma]^2], -(Re[E^(I omega) (-1 + gamma)]/Sqrt[
     1 - Abs[gamma]^2])}}
  ]

Inputs in the picture:
FullSimplify[
 omegabar[
  sutosl[{gamma, omega}]], {omega \[Element] Reals && 
   gamma \[Element] Complexes && Abs[gamma] < 1}]

-((ArcSec[Sqrt[1 - gamma^2] Sec[omega]] Sign[Sin[omega]])/Sqrt[
  Sign[1 - gamma^2]]) /. {gamma -> 0.5*Exp[I*Pi/4],  omega -> 1}

omegabar[sutosl[{gamma, omega}]] /. {gamma -> 0.5*Exp[I*Pi/4],  
  omega -> 1}

My teacher suggested not using Conjugate which FullSimplify can hardly simplify. I tried avoiding the use of Conjugate as much as possible and tried simplifying by my hands, obtaining much simplified functions as above. However, the problem remains invariant.
I searched mathematicastackexchange, but the problem is that my simplification involves only symbolic computation instead of numerical computation, as is discusssed in other posts in mathematicastackexchange.
Edit: Additional information: the output of sutosl is supposed to be a matrix in $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, and the output of omegabar is supposed to be a real number.

Just replace FullSimplify with Simplify and the problem goes away. FullSimplify got too greedy for some reason.

@Nasser Thanks. Simplify gives the desired numerical answer, but ...... shall I believe Simplify's result? I think I couldn't believe it until I find out why FullSimplify breaks down. QAQ

Your code seems to contain some error. Indeed, try to substitute: Sign[mat[[2, 1]] - mat[[1, 2]]]*ArcCos[(mat[[1, 1]] + mat[[2, 2]])/2] /. mat -> sutosl[{gamma, omega}], which lies in the core of your code, and you will get warnings. Even substitution: mat[[2, 1]] /. mat -> sutosl[{gamma, omega}] brings up the message: "Part specification mat[[2,1]] is longer than the depth of the object," pointing to an error. Since I do not know what the problem you are solving is, I cannot make any more suggestions.

until I find out why FullSimplify breaks down it could be a bug in FullSimplify as it does many more things than Simplify.  You might want to report it to WRI and see what they say.

@AlexeiBoulbitch yes, but Sign[sutosl[{gamma, omega}][[2, 1]] - sutosl[{gamma, omega}][[1, 2]]]*ArcCos[(sutosl[{gamma, omega}][[1, 1]] + sutosl[{gamma, omega}][[2, 2]])/2] works well. Let me try rewriting sutosl accordingly. Thanks!

@AlexeiBoulbitch I removed the Module in the definition of sutosl but mat[[2, 1]] /. mat -> sutosl[{gamma, omega}] is still erroneous. It seems that this error comes before replacement /., i.e. before replacement mat is just a variable but not a matrix (list), not having [[2, 1]] part.

@Nasser thanks! I'll try.
